# Sending # as dtmf in android

Tags: android, dtmf

I'm trying to make a call directly like this

```
String url = "tel:" +"029870125,198#";                              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse(url));
```

but the problem is that Android is sending `198` as `dtmf`, but the `#` is not being sent. Is there any special mechanism needed to send `#` as `dtmf`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                             
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, "#"); 
intentCallForward.setData(uri);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```